# How to setup Int. connection through Airport Express on Mac using broadband cable?

Tags: mac, internet-connection, airport-express

I have a Mac, airport express, and a broadband cable which works when i use it with PC. when I plug it into Aorport express and try setting it up using automatic settings it doesnt connect. what do i need to do??

Answer (score 1):

I would perform a [soft reset](http://www.macworld.com/article/36834/2004/08/000282.html), and if that doesn't work a [hard reset](http://www.macworld.com/article/36834/2004/08/000282.html).

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to supply more details - what happens to the light on the front of the AE, what is the Airport Utility saying.  Are there any console errors etc.
Soft & hard resets aren't a bad idea though.